# Delete minimum occurence element from Linked lists

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I need to write a code where I need to delete the minimum occurrence element in the linked list. I have an idea First point a variable to the head and then make the a variable current to point to the current element and then make an array to keep track of the counts of each element and then delete the minimum occurring element:

```
    public void deleteLeastCommon() {
    Node<T> head = getHead();
    int count = 0;
    int array [] = new int[count];
    while(current != nul){

   }

}
```

Comment: I am not able to write the code to do that if any one could help me It would be really helpful

Comment: Use a HashMap to hold your elements and their number of appearances

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a hash map to store the node(key) and the occurrence(value). Then iterate the value of map, find the minimum occurrence(value) and remove it. Print the map into a linked list.